# Plot_model() How to change legend title when color is set to black and white

Tags: r, plot, legend

In `plot_model()` function (sjPlot package), setting colors to black and white, `colors="bw"`, does not allow the user to modify the character string in the title of the legend in `legend.title`. Is there a workaround for this without modifying the data itself?

**EDIT**

Example with `colors="bw"`

```
plot_model(mod4, type="int",
           colors="bw",
           mdrt.values="minmax", 
           title = "",
           axis.title = c("Variable 1", "Response"),
           legend.title="Distance (Meters)"
           )
```

[image]

With `colors="Set1"`

```
plot_model(mod4, type="int",
           colors="Set1",
           mdrt.values="minmax", 
           title = "",
           axis.title = c("Variable 1", "Response"),
           legend.title="Distance (Meters)"
           )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'internals' of sjPlot are based on ggplot2, so you can use ggplot2 commands to customise your plot.

Example plot (from https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_marginal_effects.html):

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)
data(efc)
theme_set(theme_sjplot())

fit <- lm(barthtot ~ c12hour + neg_c_7 + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("c12hour", "c172code"))
```

[image]

With `colors = "bw"`:

```r
plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("c12hour", "c172code"), colors = "bw")
```

[image]

Changing the legend title:

```r
plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("c12hour", "c172code"), colors = "bw") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "New Title",
                        values = c(1,2,3))
```

[image]

Changing the color and size of the title:

```r
plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("c12hour", "c172code"), colors = "bw") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "New Title",
                        values = c(1,2,3)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour = "red"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

### Edit

Also, it seems that changing `legend.title` does work in my example:

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)
data(efc)
theme_set(theme_sjplot())

fit <- lm(barthtot ~ c12hour + neg_c_7 + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("c12hour", "c172code"))
```

[image]

```r
plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("c12hour", "c172code"), colors = "bw")
```

[image]

```r
plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("c12hour", "c172code"),
           colors = "bw", legend.title = "new title")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Are you able to provide a minimal reproducible example to illustrate your problem? Are you running the most up-to-date version of R/sjPlot?

Comment: I've edited to show an example of the problem. sjPlot version 2.8.15

Comment: Thanks for updating your example @kpm! It looks to me like this is a bug. There is a github issue and bugfix for this exact problem when `type = "pred"` (https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/466 / https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/commit/24c26976902259f537f3291f22c6d1ccfd564754), but the problem still occurs when `type="int"`. If you could please post a New Issue on https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues, referencing this question and the two links above, it will hopefully be straightforward for the package author/s to make the same change.